# Get player details from Google Play Games Service storage

Tags: android, api, google-play-games

I have an android game configured with Google Play Games API. API works perfectly and user can sign in, use leaderboard, earn achievements, etc. Now i want to access Player details if possible like email, name, age who are already signed in the game. 
I am doing this right now from the app itself, what if i want to access this data remotely?

Also is this possible to get all connected player details even without having their individually `Player ID`? For example, Getting a list of all the users who are signed in through web?

Answer (score 1):

From here: https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/players/get

You need to send an HTTP GET request with playerId as

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/playerId
```

This request requires authorization with the following scope

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games
```

If successful, this method returns a Players resource in the response body.

Here's the JSON template for a Player resource:

https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/players#resource

Comment: You cannot access email this way, also is this possible to get a list of all players id?

Comment: I dont THINK you can get player emails anyways as that would compromise their privacy. What do you mean by "get a list of player IDs"?

Comment: I mean, how can i get all the connected player data without having player id, its okay if email is not available. Right now i am accessing this data from app itself.

Comment: You'll probably have to upload that data from the data from the app to a SQLite database after parsing the JSON object. You can upload it to your server later.