# Play Games scope with email scope. Is there consent screen on my games?

Tags: google-play-games

I want to use /oauth2/v2/userinfo API for getting id field. 
e.g. "id": "numbers",

I have a web service(not game), and I want to identify my web users on game.
So I wrote the following code.

```
GoogleApiClient.Builder builder = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mActivity)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .addApi(Games.API)
    .addScope(new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"));
```

http://android-developers.blogspot.kr/2016/01/play-games-permissions-are-changing-in.html

I read this article.

I have a question.

Is there consent screen required on my games?

Is this code Ok?

Should I only use Game scope?

Comment: First, in the blog that you have provided by Google that asking for the Google+ scope is unnecessarily. A solution provide by them was "Don’t request any additional scopes unless you absolutely need them." Second, regarding your code and scope to use double check the *Play Games Permissions* blog to follow the correct and best practice you have to implement in your app. Here is the list of [Google APIs for Android](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/packages) including the scopes under each APIs. Should you use only Game Scope, you should if you don't have to use any other API.

Comment: Remember, Google is trying to reduce sign-in friction and unnecessary permission requests for players. Use additional APIs if it is really needed. Check this SO [35836402](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35836402/google-play-games-service-same-e-mail-account-returns-difference-id) and [35379231](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35379231/get-player-details-from-google-play-games-service-storage) for additional information. Hope it helps!